# Как мне открыть дочернее окно в PyQT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня есть программка которая делалась в `QtDesigner` и мне нужно чтобы по нажатию кнопки открывалось окно которое тоже сделано в `QtDesigner`.

Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def on_click(self):
    dialog = AnotherWindow(self)
    dialog.show()
```